# Can't select existing row via one column name

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

I have a sqlite3 database with a table called `users`. The table has a column called `activation_token` which is of type `VARCHAR(255)`.

There is a single row in this table populates this column with

```
900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0
```

I would expect the following to return that record but I get no output:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE activation_token = '900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0';
```

In fact this command's output really confuses me

```
SELECT activation_token FROM users 
where activation_token != '900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0';

900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Output of `.schema users` to verify that I'm getting the column name correct:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "email" varchar(255), "crypted_password" varchar(255), "salt" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "remember_me_token" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, "remember_me_token_expires_at" datetime DEFAULT NULL, "activation_state" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, "activation_token" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, "activation_token_expires_at" datetime DEFAULT NULL, "reset_password_token" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, "reset_password_token_expires_at" datetime DEFAULT NULL, "reset_password_email_sent_at" datetime DEFAULT NULL, "last_login_at" datetime DEFAULT NULL, "last_logout_at" datetime DEFAULT NULL, "last_activity_at" datetime DEFAULT NULL, "failed_logins_count" integer DEFAULT 0, "lock_expires_at" datetime DEFAULT NULL);
CREATE INDEX "index_users_on_activation_token" ON "users" ("activation_token");
CREATE INDEX "index_users_on_last_logout_at_and_last_activity_at" ON "users" ("last_logout_at", "last_activity_at");
CREATE INDEX "index_users_on_remember_me_token" ON "users" ("remember_me_token");
```

Output of `SELECT '->' || activation_token || '<-' FROM users;` to verify that there is no whitespace:

```
->900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0<-
```

Comment: Is there padding, whitespace, or some weird character appended to the column's value?

Comment: @Jason Not that I can see. I'm copying and pasting directly from the console and ensuring there is nothing afterwards. I've also tried inserting the value directly and getting the same result.

Comment: try doing WHERE activation_token like '%900%' or something like that

Comment: This is SQLite right? I'm guessing based on `.schema`.

Comment: @mu Yup that's right. I knew I forgot to mention something.

Comment: @Derek Yup doing like finds the record just fine as long as I have a % at the end. I can even enter the whole string and append a % and it will find it. This indicates that there is something on the end that I can't see but I can't see how I can work out what. It is definitely not whitespace.

Comment: Try WHERE trim(activation_token) = '900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0'

Comment: @Derek Okay that works but the length of the field, as given by `select length(activation_token) from users;` is 40 (the number of visible characters) so I can't see what it is trimming. No whitespace is output at all.

Comment: @mu how can I check for that? Is there a way to make the sqlite console display them?

Comment: You'd probably have to use your favorite language to pull the bytes out of SQLite and then check the bytes for zeros.

Answer (score 2):

To check what value is actually in the activation_token column I would recommend the following:

```
SELECT '%' || activation_token || '%' FROM users WHERE 1=1;
```

The percent signs should make it obvious if there is some whitespace at the beginning or end of the value.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, CONCAT is not found. Not sure if this is just in my version of sqlite or if it is not available in sqlite in general.

Comment: @Rupert: AFAIK `CONCAT` is a MySQLism, try the `||` operator instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `activation_token` value that is `'900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0'` with some trailing spaces on it. For example:

```
sqlite> create table pancakes (activation_token varchar(255));
sqlite> insert into pancakes values('900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0');
sqlite> insert into pancakes values('900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0      ');

sqlite> select activation_token from pancakes;
activation_token
900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0
900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0      

sqlite> select '->' || activation_token || '<-' from pancakes;
'->' || activation_token || '<-'
->900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0<-
->900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0      <-

sqlite> select '->' || activation_token || '<-' from pancakes where activation_token = '900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0';
'->' || activation_token || '<-'
->900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0<-

sqlite> select '->' || activation_token || '<-' from pancakes where activation_token != '900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0';
'->' || activation_token || '<-'
->900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0      <-
```

This post from the SQLite mailing list might be of interest:

> http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg30848.html

PostgreSQL 9 exhibits the same behavior, MySQL 5.1 preserves the spaces but ignores them for comparisons; there may be configuration options to alter this behavior. I don't have anything else handy so I can't check any others.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and tip. The output I get is `->900395b3d2faf7d553f719df666d1a755fb7aef0<-` i.e. no whitespace

Comment: Most SQLs ignore trailing spaces; maybe SQLlite is different.

Comment: @Malvolio: The standard leaves some wiggle room on this issue, I found a relevant post from the SQLite mailing list about this very issue (there's a link in my updated answer).

Comment: That's what I like about standards: there are so many to choose from.

Comment: @Rupert: Do you perhaps have some binary garbage at the end of your string that SQLite is choosing not to display? Try `select length(activation_token) from users` and see if that says 40.

Comment: @mu Yup its 40. *rips hair out*

Comment: Can you share the database or is the sensitive or personal information in it? There is only the one row, right?

Answer (score 0):

In your second query, you `SELECT` a column called `activation_code` while you restrict based on `activation_token`. I think you have both columns present and confuse them in your queries.